# Return empty String if match fails in function

Tags: rust

I have a function like this

```rust
fn get_html(address: &str) -> String {
    let mut response = reqwest::blocking::get(
        address,
    );

    response = response.unwrap_or_else(|_e| {String::from("")});
    response = response.text().unwrap_or_else(|_e| {String::from("")});
    return response
    }
```

Where I'm checking for html content. I would like to return an empty `String` if any kind of an error occurs somewhere in this function.
I'm not sure how to deal with this because `unwrap_or_else` expecting `Result` not `String`.

Comment: `unwrap_or_else(|_e| {String::from("")})` -> `unwrap_or_default()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reqwest::blocking::get()` function is returning a `Result<Response>`.

To obtain the html, you have to unwrap this result and call `.text()` method.

That will return a `Result<String>`, that you have to unwrap again.

In your code you assign a `String::from("")` when you unwrap the `Result<Response>`, and that is not right, because you have a Response when it is *Ok* and a String when it is an *Err*.

Instead you should match the result and return the String from the function:

```
fn get_html(address: &str) -> String {
    let mut response = reqwest::blocking::get(
        address,
    );

    match response {
        Ok(response) => response.text().unwrap_or_else(|_e| String::from("")),
        Err(_) => String::from(""),
   }
}
```

In this code, you use `unwrap_or_else()` just on the `.text()` result.
While if you have an error on the response itself, you return a String from the function.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Also the explanation is very clear!

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic way to solve your issue would be to refactor slightly your code: because code in `get_html` could fail, it's natural that its signature reflects this, so instead of returning a `String`, it could return an `Option<String>`, leaving the caller decide on what to do in this case:

```rust
fn get_html(address: &str) -> Option<String> {
    reqwest::blocking::get(address)
        .ok()?
        .text()
        .ok()
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=539dcf7fd367bb4190444e754f8d4165).
This makes the code much more straightforward. However, you may really want the signature of the function to be `-> String`, not `-> Option<String>`. In this case, there are two solutions.

The first solution would be to use the experimental `try` block. I mention this solution, not because it's currently the most adequate, but because it will be one day (most likely).

```rust
fn get_html(address: &str) -> String {
    let result: Option<_> = try {
        reqwest::blocking::get(address)
            .ok()?
            .text()
            .ok()?
     };
     result.unwrap_or_default()
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=539dcf7fd367bb4190444e754f8d4165).

*Note that, as is, Rust is not able to figure out types on its own for the `try` block, so we have to help it, which makes this more verbose. This aspect will probably improve over time, when `try` blocks are stabilized.*

Also note that, since the `Default::default` constructor of `String` produces an empty string, we can directly use `.unwrap_or_default()` instead of `.unwrap_or(String::new())` or `.unwrap_or_else(|| String::new())` (since an empty string is not allocated, the first option is also acceptable).

The second solution would simply be to add an other function with the wanted signature, and make it use the first function

```rust
fn get_html_failable(address: &str) -> Option<String> {
    reqwest::blocking::get(address)
        .ok()?
        .text()
        .ok()
}

fn get_html(address: &str) -> String {
    get_html_failable(address).unwrap_or_default()
}
```

This may seem unconvenient, but lots of libraries in Rust have internal error propagation using types that represent failure (such as `Result` or `Option`), because it's really convenient to write such functions and to compose them (both `reqwest::blocking::get` and `.text()` return a `Result`, and see how easy it is to use them in a function that returns an `Option`), and have wrapper function that expose the wanted signature (most libraries will still expose fail types, but if you are writing an application it's not necessarily the best choice).

A variable of both preceding workarounds is to "simulate" a try block in stable Rust, without relying on an additional toplevel function.

```rust
fn get_html(address: &str) -> String {
    (|| reqwest::blocking::get(address).ok()?.text().ok())()
        .unwrap_or_default()
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=539dcf7fd367bb4190444e754f8d4165).
*Note that, in this case, countrary to the `try` version, Rust is able to figure out the right types on its own*.

This is probably the least readable solution, so I wouldn't recommend it (use `try` blocks instead). But it works.